# Contenful API gives TypeError: client.getEntry is not a function

Tags: contentful, contentful-api, contentful-management

Trying to use contentfil entry with API but getting some error **TypeError: client.getEntry is not a function** . Everything seems good, googled a lot but did not find any answer.

```
            const contentful = require('contentful-management')

            const client = contentful.createClient({
            space: 'sdfdrf65435',
            accessToken: 'sdf43tgfhg34tgdfgdsf',
            host: 'preview.contentful.com'
            })
            console.log("client---->",client)
            client.getEntry('sdf34ythrgfgd')
            .then((entry) => console.log(entry))
            .catch(console.error)
```

This is the code I tried, but not working somehow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Management SDK. Taking a quick look at the [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry/get-a-single-entry/console/js), you need to do something as follow:

```js
const contentful = require('contentful-management')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: '<content_management_api_key>'
})

client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.getEnvironment('<environment_id>'))
.then((environment) => environment.getEntry('<entry_id>'))
.then((entry) => console.log(entry))
.catch(console.error)
```

If you just want to fetch content and not manipulate it from the client side, you should use the [Delivery API](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/entries/entry/get-a-single-entry/console/js).

Comment: where can i get this content_management_api_key ? can u pls help

Comment: Here's the link to the documentation that should help: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/authentication/#the-content-management-api

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because I was using the **plain API** which is better than the typical client (which you are using) as per as the documentation on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful-management#your-first-request).
with plain client you need to use **entry.get** function:

```
//first we create a client with our defaults:
const scopedPlainClient = contentful.createClient(
  {
    // This is the access token for this space. Normally you get the token in the Contentful web app
    accessToken: //your CMA access token,
  },
  {
    type: 'plain',
    defaults: {
      spaceId: //your space id,
      environmentId://your env id  typically: 'master',
    },
  }
)
```

Now, a direct call of getEntry won't work:

```
//this won't work 
await scopedPlainClient.getEntry(<entry_id>)

//this will work
copedPlainClient.entry.get({
  entryId: <entry_id>
})
```